# I can't set varibales at path of excel connection manager because of change the file name every time

Tags: excel, ssis, connection

I'd like to set the variables of path at excel connection manager, however the program i made doesn't exists the excel file because it's created while runtime.

So, I try to find out the way of setting the variables at excel connection manager, but unfortunately I can't.

Moreover, the excel file name will be changed different name every times. So ssis can't recognize the excel file I'd like to set.

I have already used script task for connecting excel file, but I abondone the way because clients enviroment doesn't suitable for excel. Only contaienr or component will be able to work.

I want to find out the way to set the variables creating at the excel connection manager path.

Comment: You can use a variable in a expression in the connection manager's properties.  If you turn on delay validation, the package will not check the connection string until it starts to read from the file.

Comment: thanks, I write I watch the excel connection manager, but I watch excel destination one. So I could find out where I shoud set.

Comment: I'll post a picture with the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to dynamically configure an excel connection manager:

1. Add a variable
2. Go to the properties of the Excel Connection manager and set Delay Validation to True
3. Also in the properties window for the connection manager, click on the ... in the expressions settings
4. In the Properties Expression Editor, select ConnectionString in the dropdown and click on the ...
5. In the expression builder window drag or type in your variable name as shown below:

[image: SettingExcelConnectionManagerWithDynamicConnection]